# Dynamically adding and removing data from Graphview

Tags: android, android-graphview

I am using graphview to dynamically create graphs which add new datapoints constantly. But I don't want to store more than 100 datapoints at a single time. So I need to remove datapoints while adding new ones. However, it seems graphview has a resetData() or removeAllSeries() which gets rid of everything. Is there a function that can achieve my need or do I have to get rid of all data?